# Delete duplicate node checking if specific keys have same values

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my db are some nodes which have this form:

```
n:Contact
{
   "name": "name surname",
   "created_timestampe": 1460411261,
   "updated_timestamp": 1494083876,
   "contact_point": [
        "+39*********"
   ]
 }
```

but there are some nodes where I have some values for the keys name and contact_point which are duplicated. I don't care about created_timestamp or updated_timestamp, but I want to delete this duplicates, checking if the contact_point value is really the same. 
I wrote this, but I'm not sure if it's correct:

```
MATCH (c:Contact)
WITH c.contact_point AS contact_point, COLLECT(c) AS contacts
WHERE SIZE(contacts) > 1
FOREACH (n IN contacts| DETACH DELETE n);
```

Answer (score 1):

You presumably don't want to delete *all* of the duplicates. To keep just one of them, do this instead (as long as you are sure it is OK to delete all the relationships of the duplicates that *are* being deleted):

```
MATCH (c:Contact)
WITH c.contact_point AS cp, COLLECT(c) AS contacts
FOREACH (n IN contacts[1..] | DETACH DELETE n);
```

Notice that the `WHERE SIZE(contacts) > 1` test is not necessary, since `contacts[1..]` will be an empty list if `contacts` has only one element.

You can do a similar thing with `c.name`.

Comment: I think it's works, thanks a lot ! So, should I do execute two query, one for c.name and one for c.contact_point ? However the value of contact_point key is an array and sometime it happens that two, three or more contacts node have the same name but the contact_point has two or three values that contain the contact_point value of another node. In this case what can I do ?

Comment: You need to make clear in your question how the two properties are related. It is not at all clear now what the constraints are.